# VisualForce {!Account.Id} returns 15 char id rather than 18

Tags: parameters, salesforce, visualforce

From the Salesforce [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/field_types.htm):

> "Because there are applications like Access which do not recognize that 50130000000014c is a different ID from 50130000000014C, **an 18-digit, case-safe version of the ID is returned by all API calls**. The 18 character IDs have been formed by adding a suffix to each ID in the Force.com API. 18-character IDs can be safely compared for uniqueness by case-insensitive applications, and can be used in all API calls when creating, editing, or deleting data."

Yet, from my Visualforce page:

**{!Account.Id}**

returns the 15-digit ID rather than the 18 digit ID.

Is there a different parameter/property I can use to give me the 18-char ID?  Why is it when the docs clearly say all API calls return the 18-char ID, Account.Id gives me the 15-char ID?

Comment: I'd suggest that as the docs are talking about systems which aren't case-sensitive and the API for external applications they only use the 18 char form there. Seems to be there's no need to use the 18 char version inside SFDC and VF pages since they know their system handles it appropriately.

Comment: I can maybe understand that, but these values are not only used internally.  We are sending ids as querystring params to our pages to integrate parts of our site with SF, but the SF ids that we have are the 18-char ids, and the ids that end up in our querystring are 15-char ids.  They should pick a standard and convert everything, everywhere to 18-char ids..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is a different parameter you can use, but there are several tools to get the 18-character ID.

Here's a list:

- [Add a Formula Field](http://salesforcevision.blogspot.com/2011/08/salesforce-18-digit-id.html)
- [Build your own Apex Function](http://salesforceapexcodecorner.blogspot.com/2011/06/convert-15-digit-sfdc-id-in-18-digit.html)
- [Use a Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bchgkjmjnmekbampjoenadmoekocpbhp)
- [Use a Google Spreadsheet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAcj9G_kFwU)

Hope that helps!

Comment: There is also SystemUtils.to18() in the apex-lang package (http://code.google.com/p/apex-lang/).

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I did add a formula field to the Account object as discussed in the first link you provided.  Seems like a hacky workaround for something that should be built-in to SF, but we're doing a lot of that!

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a couple reasons here. Visualforce is not considered an "API call" or at least not in the traditional sense. The case-insensitive 18 digit ids were added to help with data integration with systems like Access, but if you are interacting with other websites via URLs and query parameters, they are already case sensitive, so the 15 digit case-sensitive id should work find for you. To convert 18 to 15, just strip off the last 3 chars. All inbound requests into SFDC (UI, API, VF, Apex, etc) accept both 15 and 18 char ids.